# Adding a confirmation box in html submit button before passing control to view in Django

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-views, confirmation

We want to add a confirmation box in html for input type=submit button before passing control to a view in Django. We are looking to implement something similar to the onClick function.
So only when the user confirms, the view in views.py is called.
We used onclick, however, it is not working as desired.
Have you faced this situation before?

Comment: Why wouldnt onClick work? Its definately javascript issue not django. Just add javascript function which checks if confirmation is checked on submit button onclick event. Dont forget to add eventPreventDefaut() into the beginning of that event callback method

Comment: You might want to resubmit this as a Javascript question, if you want it to get more attention.

Comment: Are you trying to override the default submit action?